# the phase space distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am NOT a physicist and am hoping to get a quick answer to a basic question regarding what Boltzmann said (or meant). I (think I) understand the concept of the phase space distribution $D$ - the distribution of particles over the space of micro states, however modeled. The phase space distribution has an entropy $H$. My readings seem to suggest that physicists model some macroscopic properties as functions of $H$. My questions are summarized below:

1. Did Boltzmann suggest that the macroscopic properties depend on $D$ only through $H$, or only through $D^*$ where $D^*$ is any permuted version of $D$ (that is, being micro-state-label independent), noting that $H$ is only an one-dimensional summary of $D^*$?
2. Regardless what Boltzmann suggested, what do physicists believe nowadays?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "permuted" here?

Comment: A permuted distribution $D^*$ is a re-arranged $D$ with regard to the labels of the micro states. In other words, letting $\cal{M}(D)$ be a non-increasing-rearrangement of $D$, $\cal{M}(D)=\cal{M}(D^*)$.